# How to change \u7f51 to common character in vim?

Tags: vim, encoding, utf-8

In ruby, since it's utf-8 encoded in the system wide. so it's pretty straight forward:

string = "\u7f51\u5740\u4e0d\u80fd\u4e3a\u7a7a"

=>网址不能为空

Anyone can I tell me that how to do this in vim?

Comment: See also: **[Convert escaped codepoint to unicode character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076598)**

Answer (score 5):

If you are wanting to insert Unicode characters, see the `utf-8-typing` help.

For example, <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> `u7f51` will insert 网.

If you are wanting it in Vim scripts, you can use Unicode escapes in the same way as in Ruby; the command `echo "\u7f51\u5740\u4e0d\u80fd\u4e3a\u7a7a"` will echo the string you provide in your question.

Being aware of this, <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> comes into play, with the `"` and `=` registers; see the docs for `i_CTRL-R` and `i_CTRL-R_=` for more info.

Given the following, with the cursor inside the double-quoted string:

```
string = "\u7f51\u5740\u4e0d\u80fd\u4e3a\u7a7a"
```

Apply these keystrokes: <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

This will turn it into the following:

```
string = "网址不能为空"
```

Try to figure out how it works yourself, but I'll explain more if you can't figure it out.

Comment: thanks! ctrl-v is not work for me, the echo command works! but I don't know how to get input from the file content itself? And output the encoded character into the file

Comment: So, you are wanting to transform it inside an existing text file of that format? Have you got Ruby set up in Vim so that you can do `:ruby`?

Comment: sure I have, but I'd prefer vim native solution or vim plug-in support

Comment: @yozloy: okey dokey, genuine solution in.