# Convert escaped codepoint to unicode character

Tags: vim, utf-8, iconv

I am trying to take a chunk of JSON that has strings which contain the literal characters `\u009e` and I would like to convert those characters to its associated single unicode character, in this case `é`.

I use curl or wget to download the json which looks like:

```
{ "name": "Kitsun\u00e9" }
```

And need to translate this in Vim to:

```
{ "name": "Kitsuné" }
```

My first thought was to use Vim's iconv, but it does not evaluate the string as a single character and just returns the input.

```
let code = '\u00e9'
echo iconv(code, "UTF-8", "UTF-8")
" Prints \u00e9
```

I want to eventually use something like

```
%s;\\u[0-9abcdef]*;\=iconv(submatch(0),"UTF-8", "UTF-8");g
```

Comment: See also: **[How to change \u7f51 to common character in vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266076)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this line works for your example:

```
s#\\u[0-9a-f]*#\=eval('"'.submatch(0).'"')#
```

or

```
s#\v\\u([0-9a-f]{4})#\=nr2char(str2nr(submatch(1),16))#
```

Comment: It's possible to do the inverse? é --> \u00e9

Comment: @adelarsq yes, it is possible. use `printf` and `char2nr` function